# SQL Server auto update column contingent on another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with the following columns:

```
CREATE TABLE Projects
(
       Project_ID int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
       Project_Code varchar(255),
       Request_Date Date DEFAULT GETDATE(),
       Region varchar(255),
       Project_Location varchar(255),
       Requested_By varchar(255),
       Project_Responsibility varchar(255),
       Facility_Classification varchar(255),
       Project_Type varchar(255),
       Expected_Start_Date varchar(255),
       Expected_End_Date varchar(255),
       Work_Areas varchar(255),
       Conference_Rooms varchar(255),
       IDF_MDF varchar(255),
       Pantries varchar(255),
       Critical_Infrastructure varchar(255),
       Building_Support_Areas varchar(255),
       Data_Centers varchar(255),
       Other_Areas varchar(255),
       Project_Manager varchar(255),
       Project_Owner varchar(255),
       Project_Sponsor varchar(255),
       Functional_Currency varchar(255),
       Approval_Status varchar(255) DEFAULT 'Not yet approved',
       CIP_NCIP varchar(255),
       Capital_Expense varchar(255),
       Fiscal_Year varchar(255),
)
```

I want to update the table such that when the approval status of any record changes to approved, I want to auto populate the project code column using a combination of region, location and id.

Is this possible to do so in SQL Server? If so how?

Comment: Look into computed columns. They work just like your `DEFAULT 'Not yet approved'`. You can use a query in place of a hard coded value.

Comment: How is the approval status change? is it through another UPDATE script that you execute manually or is it through another process that you have no control of?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest removing `project_code` and adding a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE Projects 
ADD project_code AS
    CASE WHEN Approval_Status = 'Approved'
         THEN region + '-' + location + '-' + id END
```

This calculates the value on the fly -- when queried -- so it is always up-to-date.  Otherwise, you'll need a trigger to have the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

As an option you can use a trigger, this way you can also update another field if needed:

```
ALTER TRIGGER UpateValues
ON Projects
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE   
AS  
  UPDATE P
  SET P.Description = (I.region + '-' + I.location + '-' + I.id)
  FROM
  Projects P
  INNER JOIN inserted I ON I.Project_ID = P.Project_ID

GO
```

Comment: **Hey Marc**, yes, I think you were right so I **edited** my trigger, now it does the trick well.